# Problem with closure of subset of $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, orthogonality

Let $M=\{x\in l^2 | \sum_{k=1}^\infty\xi_k=0\}$. Prove that $\overline M=l^2$.

Note: $\xi_k$ is $k$th element of $x$.

Using that $M$ is linear space we can write $(M^\bot)^\bot=\overline M$, but $M^\bot$ is set of all constant sequences and his orthogonal complement isn't $l^2$.

I probably made mistakes somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: Constant sequences are not in $\ell^{2}$

Comment: Yes, you are right. What is then $M^\bot$?

Comment: Except for the sequence $0$, so if you have already proven that constant sequences are the orthogonal complement, only the $0$ can be in there

Comment: Exactly. Then its orthogonal complement is whole set $l^2$. Is it enough for proof?

Comment: Yes, I think it is

Comment: Thanks for helping.